# Why is iPad Pro suddenly displaying some apps wider than actual screen?

Tags: ios, ipad, display

[image: Screenshot of "Headspace" app showing the controls that are partially out of view]

Recently (perhaps with iOS 13.6) my iPad Pro has begun trying to display some pages slightly wider than the iPad screen. For example, one app has controls that used to appear at the left and right edges of the screen, and now they’re beyond the edges (see above image). It’s as if something thinks the iPad screen is slightly wider than it really is. I'm not able to slide the display to access the controls.

I've also seen some Safari pages with the same problem, which is why I suspect the OS rather than the apps.

I've restarted the iPad, and I've turned off all Accessibility zoom functionality, with no effect.

It doesn't happen with all apps, nor does it happen with every window of a problematic app. I haven't figured out what the common thread is.

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Comment: Have you tried restarting?  In 13.6 my iPhone suddenly developed a rotation issue where it would get stuck on landscape.  A reboot of the phone fixed it.

Comment: @Allan : I should have mentioned rebooting, and have updated my question.

Comment: This may be a bug.  13.5 and .6 introduced some UI weirdness that broken things that were working great. The rotation issue is one  and now, if I  connect my BT mouse to my iPad, i **must** have a BT keyboard connected.  The onscreen keyboard doesn't work at all.  Start with a bug report at https://apple.com/feedback